# How to transpose row values (ignoring blanks)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a code that will take products for each account and drop them into the Product Summary column.

For instance for the company on C2 'XYZ Inc' their products are widget1 (H2) widget2 (I2) and widget4 (K2).
I would like to transpose those values (ignoring the blanks) into column G.
So cell G2 would have the product widget1, cell G3 would have widget2, and cell G4 would have widget4.

Same would be applicable for company on C5.

Is this possible to code using VBA?

[image]

Here's something I found but I'm getting a compile error "Invalid outside procedure"

```
Sub RowTranspose()
Dim c As Range, v

'find last-used cell in ColG
Set c = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)

With c.Offset(-3, 0)
    v = .Resize(4, 1).Value
    .Resize(4, 1).ClearContents 
    .Resize(1, 4).Value = Application.Transpose(v)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There is probably a VBA, yes.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I'm looking online, but cant find anything. Perhaps cause I'm new with VBA and struggling to understand what each line means.

Answer (score 2):

Stackoverflow is not a site where users will write code for you without you showing some effort.  However, I can give you a logical outline of what your program should do.  If you write the code and add it to your original question, we can help you further.

- Define variables
- For each company you are looking to work with:

  - Scan over the row.  If there is a value in a cell, add the value to an array.  If not, skip.
  - Copy the items in your String array to the column that you want, one cell at a time.

That's about it.  There are probably a million other ways to do this which are more efficient, but this is an intuitive way of going about it.

Comment: If you have small blocks of code, try encasing them in the ` character (above your Tab key), and if you have large blocks, append them to your original question